# Reading an address containing 11111111 as an unsigned int shows 4294967295

Tags: c++

So, I was trying some stuff and I noticed that if you read one address that contains 11111111 as an unsigned int it shows that is value is 4294967295 and not 255, why is that?

Example of the code:

```
    unsigned int a = 255;
    unsigned int* p = &a;
    char *p0 = (char*)p;
    cout << (void*)p0 << " " <<(unsigned int)*p0<<endl;
```

Comment: There's no number 11111111 in your code.

Comment: @interjay: There's of course a 0xb11111111.

Comment: You're just printing the addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `char *p0 = (char*)p;` Here `p0` points at the lowest byte of `p`. What value that happens to be stored there depends on endianess. Could be 0x00 (Big Endian) or 0xFF (Little Endian).
  [What is CPU endianness?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640)
- `*p0` here you access the contents of the supposed `char`. Since `char` has implementation-defined signedness, it could either manage numbers -128 to 127  (assuming 2's complement) or 0 to 255. [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)
- Your particular system seems to use signed `char`, 2's complement, Little Endian. Meaning that the raw binary value 0xFF gets interpreted as -1 decimal.
- `(unsigned int)*p0` forces a conversion from -1 to `unsigned int` type. This is done after this well-defined rule (C 6.3.1.4, same rule applies in C++):

  > Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
  > subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
  > until the value is in the range of the new type.
- `-1` + `UINT_MAX` + one more =
  `-1` + `UINT_MAX` + `1` =
  `UINT_MAX` =
  `4294967295` on your 32 bit system.

Lesson learnt: never use `char` for anything but text, never use it to store values. If you need an 8 bit integer type or something to represent raw binary, use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now this got me thinking: Is there any way of reading the bit content of an address (without considering it int, char, etc…)?

Comment: @ladca The bitwise operators only work with integer types.

Answer (score 1):

Line 4 is reading the *representation* of the object `a` as `char`, which is just about the only time it's legal (not undefined) to access an object with an lvalue not matching the actual type of the object. C allows plain `char` to be a signed or unsigned type (implementation-defined). On the implementation you're using, `char` is a signed type, and `unsigned int` is represented in little endian (low-order byte first), so you read the bit pattern with 8 one bits, and this represents the `char` value -1.

Subsequently converting (via cast or implicitly) the value -1 to `unsigned int` reduces it modulo `UINT_MAX+1`, producing the value `UINT_MAX`.